# Mocking functions inside a for loop in R

Tags: r, loops, unit-testing, testthat

I'm using testthat package for unit testing in R. I have a function **CalcByResultSubModel** which has one more function **CalculateX** which is called  inside the main function. This is the main function,

```
CalcByResultSubModel = function(doll_data, fn_master, modelPath) {
  # load sub model result
  load(modelPath)
  
  # calculation
  for(abc in c("ABC", fn_master$fn_a)) {
    
    # columns
    col_name = paste0("x", abc)    
    iterModel = resultSubmodel[[abc]]
    
    # calculate yhat X
    doll_data[, col_name] = iterModel %>% 
      purrr::map(., function(imodel) {
        CalculateX(data, imodel)
      }) %>% 
      as.data.frame(.) %>%
      apply(., 1, mean)
    
    message(paste(col_name, "calculated"))      
  }
```

This is the function **CalculateX**

```
CalculateX = function(data, model) {
  iterData = data %>% 
    dplyr::select(model$feature_names) %>% 
    as.matrix(.)
  set.seed(131)
  result = predict(model, iterData, missing = NA)
  result = matrix(result, 2)[2, ]
  
  return(result)
}
```

Inorder to perform unit testing we have to mock the function *CalculateX*. But the complexity here is that, the function is called inside for loop in the main function. I'm quite new to this scenario in my unit testing. Can anyone help me with the mocking of the function in a for loop? This is the code for mocking and I tried this.

```
local_mock(CalculateX = function(data, model){
                  for (abc in c("ABC", fn_master$fn_a)
                  case_when(
                    abc == "feature1" ~ .ReadCsvWrapper("feature1.csv"),
                    abc == "feature2" ~ .ReadCsvWrapper( "feature2.csv"),
                    abc == "feature3" ~ .ReadCsvWrapper("feature3.csv"))
            })
But the above approach doesn't seem to work for me. Can anyone help me with this?
```

Comment: You don't say how you were doing the mocking, or what went wrong.  Could you add that to your question?  Otherwise it's not obvious why the for loop makes any difference at all.

Comment: Yes I will add the mocking part which I tried.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems in your code.  First, `CalcByResultSubModel` calls `CalculateX` in the loop

```
for(abc in c("ABC", fn_master$fn_a)) {
    
    # columns
    col_name = paste0("x", abc)    
    iterModel = resultSubmodel[[abc]]
    
    # calculate yhat X
    doll_data[, col_name] = iterModel %>% 
      purrr::map(., function(imodel) {
        CalculateX(data, imodel)
      }) %>% 
      as.data.frame(.) %>%
      apply(., 1, mean)
    
    message(paste(col_name, "calculated"))      
  }
```

so you don't need to put that `for(abc in c("ABC", fn_master$fn_a))` into the mocked function.  Just set it up to return results similar to what one call to the real function would do.

The second problem is that in the real `CalculateX`, you have `set.seed(131)`.  This is almost certainly a bad idea.  It resets the random number generator to a fixed setting every time `CalculateX` is called, which makes it completely non-random, and also makes calls to random number functions afterwards repeat their outputs.

It's often a good idea to set the seed once at the top of your testing script so that tests are predictable, but resetting it as often as you did is not.